# Spawn bombs and throw them to the player in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got a small arena where the player can move on. At the sides of the area there are spawners. These spawners instantiate bombs and should throw them at the player.

For the direction I actually use

`transform.lookAt(playerTransform);`

So this is a rough map

[image: Map]

So the spawners are rotating around the map. They move from one point to the next point.

My bomb object got a rigidbody attached and the gravity is activated. I just need to find out how to make a spawner throwing a bomb to the player.

```
public class BombSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0, 3)]
    [SerializeField]
    private int nextPointIndex; // set the first targetpoint

    private Vector3[] targetPoints = {
        new Vector3(-15,0,15),
        new Vector3(15,0,15),
        new Vector3(15,0,-15),
        new Vector3(-15,0,-15)};

    private float movementSpeed = 10;

    GameObject bombPrefab;

    Transform player;

    private void Start()
    {
        bombPrefab = Resources.Load(StringCollection.BOMB) as GameObject;
        player = Globals.GetPlayerObject().transform;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.LookAt(player); // set the object rotation

        Vector3 nextPoint = targetPoints[nextPointIndex]; // get the target point
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, nextPoint, movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime); // move the spawner
        if (transform.position == nextPoint) // point reached? set a new point 
        {
            if (nextPointIndex < targetPoints.Length - 1)
                nextPointIndex++;
            else
                nextPointIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

So I could write a method like this

```
void SpawnBomb()
{
GameObject spawnedBomb = Instantiate(bombPrefab);
}
```

but how do I achieve the throwing mechanic? For a first try, the targetPoint is `player.position` that should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the direction from spawner to the current position of the target, spawn the bomb and add force to that bomb using the direction you just got.

In order to do this you should substract your spawner's position from your target position.

```
Vector3 dir = target.transform.position - transform.position;
```

Now that you have the direction you can spawn your bomb and `AddForce()` to it. To add force you need to call the Rigidbody component of your spawned Bomb, like this:

```
spawnedBomb.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(dir.normalized * force, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Where `dir` is the direction towards the target (normalized - so the distance doesn't matter) and `force` is pretty much the speed of the bomb.

Here you can read more about [Rigidbody.AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html).

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one. Just one typo: target.transform.position - transform.position

Comment: Yes I changed the drag of the bomb and the mass, this looks fine!